# Need to configure Jaeger with c# application

Tags: c#, .net, jaeger

I have a c# sample app that can send the trace to the console. How can i send the trace to the Jaeger running locally?

i am using Jaeger running locally at jaeger-all-in-one --collector.zipkin.host-port=:9411

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;

// Define some important constants and the activity source
var serviceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService";
var serviceVersion = "1.0.0";

// Configure important OpenTelemetry settings and the console exporter
using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
    .AddSource(serviceName)
    .SetResourceBuilder(
        ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
            .AddService(serviceName: serviceName, serviceVersion: serviceVersion))
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .Build();




var MyActivitySource = new ActivitySource(serviceName);

using var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("SayHello");
activity?.SetTag("foo", 1);
activity?.SetTag("bar", "Hello, World!");
activity?.SetTag("baz", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```